# Trouble starting cosmos emulator from Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I'm tryng to set up a CI/CD pipeline with the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator build task in Azure DevOps.
I've installed it from the marketplace, and YAML file contains:

```
> task: CosmosDbEmulator@2 inputs:
>     containerName: 'azure-cosmosdb-emulator'
>     enableAPI: 'SQL'
>     portMapping: '8081:8081, 8901:8901, 8902:8902, 8979:8979, 10250:10250, 10251:10251, 10252:10252, 10253:10253, 10254:10254,
> 10255:10255, 10256:10256, 10350:10350'
>     hostDirectory: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\azure-cosmosdb-emulator'
```

Running this results in failure " The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable", so I added this to the YAML:

```
  task: DockerInstaller@0
  displayName: Docker Installer
  inputs:
    dockerVersion: 17.09.0-ce
    releaseType: stable
```

resulting in failure:

> error during connect: (...): open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system
> cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on
> Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error
> may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
> New-CosmosDbEmulatorContainer : Could not create container
> azure-cosmosdb-emulator from
> mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/windows/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest"

I'm relatively new to azure pipelines and docker, so any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Which agent pool are you using? Azure Cosmos DB Emulator currently doesn’t support hosted VS2019 agent pool. However, the emulator already comes with VS2019 installed and you use it by starting the emulator with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UviO.png) PowerShell cmdlets. You can refer to this  official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd#create-a-build-definition).

Comment: Tried your way, but only got: "Starting CosmosDB Emulator
Import-Module : The specified module 'C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB 
Emulator/PSModules/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any 
module directory." :(

Answer (score 0):

`error during connect: (...): open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect.`

Above error you encountered is because the docker is not installed in your build agent, or the docker client is not successfully started up. DockerInstaller@0 task only install Docker cli, it doesnot install docker client.

See below extract from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd#create-a-build-definition).

> The agent pool to be selected for this CI should have Docker for Windows installed unless the installation is done manually in a prior task as a part of the CI. See Microsoft hosted agents article for a selection of agent pools; we recommend to start with Hosted VS2017.

As above document recommended. Please use hosted vs2017 agent to run your pipeline. Set the `pool` section in your yaml file like below: See [pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#pool) docuemnt.

```
pool: 
  vmImage: vs2017-win2016
```

If you are using self-hosted agent. Please install [docker client](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) in your self-hosted agent machine. And make sure the docker client is up and running.